# VirtualBox Kernels are not working

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, virtualbox, chroot

Whenever I try to load the VirtualBox kernel module, this happens:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox start
* Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
* modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
[fail]
```

Associated `dmesg` output:
    [10890.689331] Chromium OS LSM: init_module denied module="/lib/modules/3.8.11/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko" pid=28313 cmdline="modprobe vboxdrv"

**EDIT***

Ive gotton past the

```
    * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
```

now i get

```
     * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
     * No suitable module for running kernel found
```

so i did uname -r to see if i installed a header and got

```
     (cloudyjr)volt@localhost:~$ uname -r
     3.8.11
```

**EDIT***

So after i fixed this issue i come across another one i launch virtualbox in command line and i get

```
    (cloudyjr)volt@localhost:~/Downloads$ virtualbox
    WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. 
    Either there is no module available for the current kernel (3.8.11)
    or it failed to load.
    Please recompile the kernel module and install it by


    (cloudyjr)volt@localhost:~/Downloads$ virtualbox
```

WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.8.11) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

```
       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.


    You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

so i obey master terminal and run the command

```
   (cloudyjr)volt@localhost:~/Downloads$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
   Running in chroot, ignoring request.
   Running in chroot, ignoring request.
   Running in chroot, ignoring request.
   Running in chroot, ignoring request.
   vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
   vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
   vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
   vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

   There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
    /sbin/vboxconfig
```

as root.
        Running in chroot, ignoring request.
        Running in chroot, ignoring request.
        Running in chroot, ignoring request.
        Running in chroot, ignoring request.

so now i use dmesg to check the error

```
    [ 1353.252260] Chromium OS LSM: init_module locking-ignored
    module="/lib/modules/3.8.11/misc/vboxdrv.ko" pid=32049
    cmdline="/sbin/modprobe vboxdrv"
    [ 1353.280366] vboxdrv: Found 2 processor cores
    [ 1353.287097] supdrvGipCreate: failed to allocate the GIP page. rc=-26
```

Omg virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

Module Locking

If you are familiar with compiling your own kernels you will need to take a look at the Chromium documentation.

From: https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/kernel-faq

Loading Kernel modules from outside the root filesystem

If you need to load kernel modules from a location other than the root filesystem, module locking must be disabled. Either a kernel command line option can be used:

```
lsm.module_locking=0
```

There are scripts that can do for you if you do not want to spend the time to do the research.

From: https://github.com/divx118/crouton-packages/blob/master/README.md

For being able to load modules outside /lib/modules from chromeos we will need to disable module_locking. This can be done by changing the kernel flags.

EDIT after your edit: I did some quick googling for you. Here is a guide to setup Virtualbox in Chrome OS: https://techblog.jeppson.org/2015/11/install-virtualbox-on-a-chromebook/

Comment: Look at my edit

Comment: another edit :)

Comment: Is there another edit?

Comment: Did you get this worked out?

Comment: I wiped my chroot gonna reinstall virtualbox using the guide u gave me and ill see

Comment: Did this work for you?